# Can I add other key holders to an existing PGP file?

Tags: pgp

If I have a file that I encrypted with PGP and I'd like to allow other people to view the file after I performed the original encryption can I simply add them to the PGP payload?  Since PGP creates a symmetric encryption key that is used to encrypt the file's content, and encrypts that symmetric key with each user's public key then it seems like I could add or remove people from the file by modifying the header and not re-encrypting the entire file again.  Is that possible with PGP tools?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While this would theoretically be possible, the common tools do not support it. PGP has `--export-session-key` and [GnuPG](https://gnupg.org/documentation/manpage.html) has `--show-session-key` & `--override-session-key`, but the latter is only used for decryption. **For encryption, a new random session key is generated every time.**

> `--show-session-key`
>
> Display the session key used for one message. See
> `--override-session-key` for the counterpart of this option.
>
> We think that Key-Escrow is a Bad Thing; however the user should have
> the freedom to decide whether to go to prison or to reveal the content
> of one specific message without compromising all messages ever
> encrypted for one secret key. DON'T USE IT UNLESS YOU ARE REALLY
> FORCED TO DO SO.
>
> `--override-session-key string`
>
> Don't use the public key but the session key string. The format of
> this string is the same as the one printed by `--show-session-key`.
> This option is normally not used but comes handy in case someone
> forces you to reveal the content of an encrypted message; using this
> option you can do this without handing out the secret key.